# tFlowToIterate with BigDataBatch job

Tags: bigdata, talend

I have currently a simple standard job on Talend doing this :
[image: Current version of the job]
It simply reads a file of several lines (tHDFSInput), and for each line of this file (tFlowToIterate), I create a INSERT query "INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM" based on what I read in my file (tHiveRow). And it works well, it's just a bit slow.

I now need to modify my "Standard" job to make a "Big Data Batch" job in order to make it faster, and also because we asked me to only make Big Data Batch from now on.
The thing is that there is no tFlowToIterate and no tHiveRow component with Big Data Batch...

How can I do this ?

Thank's a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Though I haven't tried this solution, I think this can help you.

1. Create hive table upfront.
2. Place tHDFSConfiguration component in the job and provide cluster details.
3. Use tFileInputDelimited component. On providing storage configuration as tHDFSConfiguration(defined in step1), this will read from HDFS.
4. Use tHiveOutput component. Connect tFileInputDelimited to tHiveOutput. In tHiveOutput, you can provide the table, format and save mode.

Comment: How can I iterate on each line of the tFileInputDelimited with this method ?

Comment: The above solution works if you are trying to load the HDFS file into hive table.

Comment: Create a standard job and try to convert those insert queries into the data itself. This data you will have in  a delimited file and keep that file in HDFS. Now load this into hive table

Comment: I don't want to load the hdfs file into my table. I want to generate a query from each line of the file. And insert into the table the result of each query.

Comment: To my knowledge, BigData Batch job is not meant for these kind of iterative work loads.

Comment: Inserting into hive table using INSERT INTO clause will spawn MR/Tez/Spark job behind the scene and creates smaller files. That's going to slow down your job

Comment: Knowing that there is no real solution for this is an anwser good enough for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In order to load HDFS into Hive without modification on the data maybe you can use only one component : `tHiveLoad`

Insert your HDFS path inside the component.

tHiveLoad documentation : https://help.talend.com/reader/hCrOzogIwKfuR3mPf~LydA/ILvaWaTQF60ovIN6jpZpzg

Comment: I can't see any tHiveLoad component with Big Data batch on Talend. And even if I had, that's not enough :s